# What does the 'final' keyword mean?

Tags: d, final

On this [documentation page of interfaces on dlang.org](http://dlang.org/interface.html), it says interfaces must implement final methods. What are final methods? The keyword doesn't seem to be mentioned on any other page.

There is [this page](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/final-const-invariant.html) I found, but it seems to be a remain from the ancient D1.

Is a final function simply a function returning an immutable result? Does the keyword even still exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A final function is one that cannot be overridden in a child class (the opposite of a virtual function).

All templates are final, so any template in an interface must have a function body or else you'll get a linker error.

Answer (score 11):

From [Virtual Functions](http://dlang.org/function.html#virtual-functions):

> Functions marked as `final` may not be overridden in a derived class, unless they are also `private`.

Comment: "unless they are also `private`." - Anyone cares to explain? How can you override a private final method in a derived class?

Comment: @Sebastian the wording is a bit incorrect I guess. A private function is not derived, so "overridden" here means having a function in a derived class with the same name. Those two functions have no connection with each other, so the `final` modifier does not apply.

Answer (score 4):

beside what the other answers have said:

an interface may specify a final function and implement it directly

```
interface Foo{
    int bar();

    final int doublefoobar(){
        return bar()*2;
    }
}
```